# How can I create properties in Visual studio 2010 ultimate modeling project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uml

I want to create properties in class. Where can I create them in attributes or operations?

I want to create get only property like

```
 string MyString { get; }
```

[image: This image shows the class]

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attributes == properties

operations == methods

For a read only property select the clas diagram and, in the properties window, change "Is Read Only" to true.

Comment: A variable? If you mean a variable backed property you can do that in the actual code. If you mean a field, I don't think it's supported through the diagram. But you can expose it through code as well. Remember this is a class diagram and and it doesn't care so much about the inner workings until you start modeling it's relationship to other classes. Hope that helps.